# Native library, required by Java OpenAL

Tags: java, shared-libraries, openal, openal-soft

I'm trying to use Java OpenAL library. I have a problem with importing native library called libsoft_oal.so. Java OpenAL is dependent upon OpenAL soft implementation. I tried to build it according to their readme on github and it seems that only libopenal.so library is compiled. Java OpenAL wasn't updated for 4 years so it seemed to me that the library was simply renamed. I renamed the library but with no luck. I think my library path is correct and I tried to run jvm with java.library.path parameter but with no luck. 
Here is the stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'soft_oal': libsoft_oal.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:169)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:242)
    at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.<init>(Library.java:140)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:368)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:353)
    at org.urish.openal.jna.ALFactory.<init>(ALFactory.java:16)
    at org.urish.openal.OpenAL.<init>(OpenAL.java:24)
    at defaultpackage.SoundTest.<init>(SoundTest.java:22)
    at defaultpackage.SoundTest.main(SoundTest.java:17)
:run FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

When I load the library with System.loadLibrary("soft_oal"); everythinkg works as expected.
This is the problematic part in library:

```
public class ALFactory {
    private static final String DEFAULT_DLL_NAME = "soft_oal";

    public final AL al;
    public final ALC alc;
    public final ALExt alext;

    public ALFactory() {
        al = (AL) Native.loadLibrary(DEFAULT_DLL_NAME, AL.class);
        alc = (ALC) Native.loadLibrary(DEFAULT_DLL_NAME, ALC.class);
        alext = (ALExt) Native.loadLibrary(DEFAULT_DLL_NAME, ALExt.class);
    }

    public ALFactory(File dllPath) throws FileNotFoundException {
        String dllName = DEFAULT_DLL_NAME;
        if (dllPath != null) {
            if (!dllPath.exists()) {
                throw new FileNotFoundException(dllPath.getAbsolutePath());
            }
            System.setProperty("jna.library.path", dllPath.getParent());
            dllName = dllPath.getName();
        }

        al = (AL) Native.loadLibrary(dllName, AL.class);
        alc = (ALC) Native.loadLibrary(dllName, ALC.class);
        alext = (ALExt) Native.loadLibrary(dllName, ALExt.class);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to solve this without directly modifying the library? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've edited the library and everything works fine now. I've also created a pull request on GitHub.